# How to get data from database table and update that data into another table in hibernate? I have done it in JSP but i want to do in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am developing an application and i want to get data from a table and want to update another table from that data. I have done it in JSP but now i just started to work on hibernate so i want to do it in hibernate.

I have 2 tables post_table and user_table in my database. I am fetching data from post_table and want to update user_table from that data. Here is my **JSP** code..

```
String sql = "SELECT uid,SUM(value) AS SumByUID FROM post_table group by uid;"
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
String mySum = rs.getString("SumByUID");
String u_id = rs.getString("uid");

String sql1 = "update user_table set rank='"+mySum+"' where uid='"+u_id+"'";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
pst.executeUpdate();
}
```

I tried to do in hibernate and i fetched data from post_table. Here is my Entity class **Post.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Post implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="uid")
private long userId;

@Column(name="value")
private long val;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public long getVal() {
    return val;
}

public void setVal(long val) {
    this.val = val;
}

}
```

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Post> getPostList() throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Result.class));
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.sum("val"), "topValue");
    projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"), "uid");
    cr.setProjection(projList);
    List postList = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return postList;
}
```

I fetched data from post_table and set the result in **Result.java**. Here is my Reslut.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Result implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="rank")
private long topValue;

private long uid;


public long getTopValue() {
    return topValue;
}
public void setTopValue(long topValue) {
    this.topValue = topValue;
}

public long getUid() {
    return uid;
}
public void setUid(long uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

And here is my **Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Post> getEmployee() {

    List<Post> postList = null;
    try {
        postList = profileService.getPostList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return postList;
}
```

Please help me because i am unable to update user_table with that data.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: where are you doing update query with hibernate ?

Comment: no i have done only half work..i fetched data from post_table but want to update that data into user_table

Comment: i didn't write update query because i dont know how to write

Comment: Why do you want to use hibernate for this? Because you can? Also why 2 queries and not just a single update query?

Comment: i am working in a company and they said to me to work on hibernate and i  am using 2 queries because i want to fetch record from one table and update another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code snap, I hope it helps :)

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public List<Result> getPostList() throws Exception {
      session = sessionFactory.openSession();
      tx = session.beginTransaction();

      Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
      ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
      projList.add(Projections.sum("val"), "topValue");
      projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"), "uid");
      cr.setProjection(projList);
      cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Result.class));
      List<Result> postList = cr.list();
      // please make sure that you are using the class field name rather than database field name in below query.
      String updateHql = "update Result set topValue = :topValue where uid = :uid";
      Query query = null;
      for(Result result : postList){
        query=session.createQuery(updateHql);
        query.setLong("topValue", result.getTopValue());
        query.setLong("uid", result.getUid());
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
      }

      session.flush();
      tx.commit();
      return postList;
  }
```

Comment: i am getting error in return type of method.. List<Post> should be List<Result> or change type of  postList to List<Post>

Comment: getting this error while running the project ..... java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.artle.model.Result
 at com.artle.dao.ProfileDataDAOImpl.getPostList(ProfileDataDAOImpl.java:152)

Comment: and line on 152 no. is   for(Result result : postList){

Comment: any error now  ?, please see updated answer and try.

Comment: Please chk my Result.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84067/discussion-between-nadeem-ahmed-and-vishal-zanzrukia).

Comment: Actually i have 2 columns in user_table id and rank . both are INTEGER types

Comment: now ... org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Result is not mapped [update Result set topValue = :topValue where uid = :uid]  :(

Comment: you are welcome :) You should up-vote the answer, so it will helpful to others :)